Studying Uniform Convergence on Fourier Series
I am studying for first time Fourier Series Theory and usually it appears the problem of show that the Series of a given map converges or not, puntually or uniformly. It seems easy in many cases to show both the puntually and uniformly convergence, but I get stuck when I try to show that a series which we know that converges puntually does not do it uniformly.
For example, given $f: (-\pi , \pi ) \rightarrow \Bbb{R}, x \mapsto x$ its Fourier Series is $$Sf(x) = \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \sin (kx) $$
The puntually convergence is given by the Dini's Condition since $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |\frac{f(x+u) - f(x)}{u} | du = 2 \pi < + \infty$
I have seen that a usual "trick" is to show that $\sup |s_n (x) - f(x) |$ does not converge to $0$, where here $s_n$ are the partial sums. In this case, $s_n (x) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \sin (kx) $ . In order to find the supremum, I have tried to derivate and find it, I mean: $$\frac{d}{dx} (s_n (x) - f(x)) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} \cos (kx) - 1 = 0$$
The problem is that this seems impossible to resolve generally when $n \geq 2$. Is there any way or trick better than this?

Hint: The cosine sum is the real part of an alternating geometric series in the variable $z =e^{ix}$.

@mathfont If I am not wrong, by using what you comment we have that $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} \cos (kx) = \frac{1}{2} [ 1 + (-1)^{n+1} \frac{ \cos ( n x ) + \cos ( (n + 1) x ) } { 1 + \cos x } ]$. How can we apply this here? The presence of the cosines of multiple of $x$ seems complicated to work with.

Perhaps the Wikipedia article on Gibbs phenomenon provides some insight.

Brute force calculation will be tedious.I would try this. Discontinuities of $f(x)$ are at $x=\pm \pi$, so that is where Gibb's phenomenon will concentrate. Thus try exploring what happens when $x= \pi+ \epsilon$ in cases where $n$ is odd and even separately.  An easier approach (proof by contradiction)  is to use the general principle that the uniform limit of continuous functions would have to be continuous.

@MathFont But if the uniform limit exists, it has to be the same as the puntual limit, is not it? In this case, it would be $f(x) = x$, which is continuous.

The function $f$  should be regarded as a periodic function. Then you will see it has a discontinuity at $\pm \pi$.
